# Is it ok to request for answer instead of comment with a comment message?

Tags: discussion, comments, answers

I got some furious commments once I long ago requested someone to leave his comment as an answer so that I could accept it and the points would go to the right person. Is it allowed to do such a thing or is that kind of "leading people to answer" not allowed through comments?

Comment: Besides the good answers you've received below, if the comment was particularly rude or out of order, by all means flag it.

Comment: I'll do that in future. This case is so old I cannot anymore remember the right question. I was just ending now to similar situation and that's why I wanted the clarification.

Comment: Odd that the person would be rude. You're trying to reward them...

Comment: I don't find anything like this in your history, and I find it unlikely anybody would be "furious" about this. There's zero wrong with nudging someone to convert a comment into an answer, and I just don't see, unless there was a *massive* mis-communication, that anybody would react angrily to the suggestion.

Comment: Time goes and my mind makes short-cuts on things. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939570/glassfish-3-1-credential-error-in-eclipse#comment8300880_6939570) was the comment that was said to be "gaming" and actually when now looking for it, it really is somehow out of the legal area. I was asking if the asker person would accept answer if I turn my comment to answer, and that is little bit on gray area. Still it let me thinking seriously about commenting; what to comment and what not.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The correct response is:

> @Commenter Thanks, that solves my problem, can you please turn it into an answer so I can accept it?

If there is no response in a few days:

1. Add your own answer.
2. Copy the text of the comment.
3. Make it community wiki.
4. Link to the comment.

And if you get answers, it is nice (also increases the chance of positive responses in the future) to upvote the good answers, downvote the wrong answers and accept the best answer.

Comment: 5. Accept your own answer (after the required waiting period).

Comment: @TRiG, yes and no, accepting is a nice thing to do, but it is not required.

Comment: @Gamecat Wouldn't you want to accept to make it more obvious that the answer provided is the one that worked?

Comment: @Gamecat None of the steps you've provided are "required", they are all just what they community considers to be the most appropriate response, and the community would also consider accepting the answer that you used to solve your question as appropriate.

Comment: If you've waited a few days after prompting a commentator, I'm not sure I'd even bother with the CW step. Earning a few rep points for taking the trouble to come back a few days later and square this away seems fair enough to me.

Answer (score 17):

This is absolutely the right thing to do.

If the commenter does not respond in a while, just post the answer yourself (as a community wiki so none can spite you for wanting the rep yourself) and accept that.