# My question was resolved through a comment

Tags: discussion, support

A kind person resolved [an issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11989283/c-alias-for-anonymous-c-type) by a throwaway one-liner in a comment instead of an answer. Bearing in mind that I cannot seem to vote on their comment, how do I:

1. Reward them with some reputation?
2. Suppress my question from the main unanswered list without affecting point 1?

Please resist the urge only to comment in response to this!

Comment: Related: [Is it ok to request for answer instead of comment with a comment message?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143611/is-it-ok-to-request-for-answer-instead-of-comment-with-a-comment-message)

Comment: If you really just forgot an include, it is `too localized`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In general, you can tell the commenter to add their comment as an answer, and that you'll accept it. Not many folks would turn down the easy rep.

In this case, however, I would tend to agree with the others: it is not a valuable question, because it is a fairly trivial error, and the "solution" is unlikely to help future readers.

Comment: I agree that the question is too localised and have voted to close for that reason. @mosi Nothing personal, that's just the way SO works. At least you solved your problem.

Comment: @vascogotlost Thanks, yes. Do you know if clicking the "delete" button will register my vote to close the question in question, or is it heavier-handed? (I have just tried searching for an answer to this.)

Comment: @mosi better to let it close as a duplicate IMHO, then the issue is easier to search for.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Do you mean that if I just leave the question alone, vascogotlost's vote will cause it to close? Also, someone else has answered it now; will I be penalised for not accepting the answer?

Comment: There's no penalty for not accepting an answer, unless you consider the social ribbing you might get if you do so often and your question gets attention from people who place a high value on such things ([which they shouldn't](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136951/lets-stop-displaying-a-users-accept-rate)). As for voting to close, unless it's a moderator, it requires consensus - so one person's vote doesn't close a question unless they're the 5th. And closing a question isn't necessarily a bad thing.

Answer (score 4):

Aside from telling the commenter to post something as an answer, if they don't actually do that you can always answer your own question and credit them in it!  If you don't want to reap karma from it (if you feel it's unearned) you can always make your answer a community wiki answer.